# Why do some RF noise sources have ENR specified and others do not?

Tags: rf, noise

What is the difference between a noise source like the [PE85N1019](https://www.pasternack.com/images/ProductPDF/PE85N1019.pdf) and a noise source like the [PE85N1012](https://www.pasternack.com/images/ProductPDF/PE85N1012.pdf)?

- What are their different use cases?
- Can the PE85N1012 be used for noise figure measurement?  If yes how do you calculate its ENR?

Answer (score 0):

*The* most important difference is their output range, these two generators works in two different RF bands.

Also the power supply is different. If you don't have 28V around and you don't need 3GHz the 1012 is probably cheaper.

As for the ENR calculation it's better explained in many articles, looks for application notes from manufactures (R&S is one of the major ones, but other have docs too). Essentially you measure the signal with the noise source off and on and then 'compare' them to give a noise figure

Comment: Sorry but your answer does not cover my question.
I did not ask about a comparison of their specs (e.g. frequency range, power supply, etc). What I ask is why for example the one has an ENR spec and why the other does not. 
Finally, the procedure you describe is not for calculating ENR but for calculating the Noise Figure when you know the ENR.
Thank you for the answer though.